# Python logging define schedule erase of log file

Tags: python, logging

Below is my current logging configuration.

I would like to know how can I get my log file cleared every 2 days, as I do have my script running on crontab schedule daily during the day.

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('MyLog')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)-5.5s - %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(
    'MyLog.log', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Here's an Example which supposed to clear the log file after each 2 min.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

logger = logging.getLogger('MyLog')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)-5.5s - %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename='MyLog.log', when='M', interval=2, encoding='utf-8')

file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.info('Hi')
```

Output after several running is below (log file not cleared):

```
2021-04-24 23:14:24 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:15:26 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:15:33 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:15:39 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:15:40 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:15:57 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:16:07 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:16:11 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:16:16 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:16:22 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:16:23 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:16:34 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
2021-04-24 23:17:08 - MyLog - INFO  - Hi
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, i came across that before posting my question. but just want to confirm if that's will handle the job ? `TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='MyLog.log', when='D', interval=2, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Perhaps you could test it (maybe on a shorter timescale...) and find out?

Comment: @jonrsharpe i tried that out with 2 minute interval [here](https://bpa.st/ZMHQ) but the log file didn't cleared.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you give a [mre] of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
file_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
  filename='MyLog.log', when='D', interval=2, encoding='utf-8', backupCount=1)
```

You need a `backupCount` parameter to delete the old log files.